# Specifying assembly in ResourceManager constructor (c#/.net)

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to create an instance of ResourceManager:

```
public ResourceManager(baseName, Assembly assembly)
```

I know the name of the assembly that the resource is in (it's not the executingassembly), and it's referenced in the project, but how do I specify it here in the code (using the above constructor)?

May be a bit of a stupid question, but I'm a bit stuck!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to grab an assembly reference is via a type that you know is declared in the assembly.  e.g.: `typeof(SomeKnownType).Assembly`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the method [`Assembly.GetAssembly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getassembly.aspx), perhaps:

```
Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(SomeClassInTheAssembly));
```

...or simply pick up the assembly from a known type:

```
typeof(SomeClassInTheAssembly).Assembly;
```

Either way, a `Type` from the given assembly is your key.

Answer (score 1):

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(ClassInThatAssembly));
ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("resString",asm);
```

Did you try this?

Comment: No - having a slightly dumb day ;)